# Calculating the limit $\lim_{c\rightarrow 1+}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{\log n}{\log c}\rfloor}(-1)^j\binom{z}{j}c^j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Does anyone know how to calculate, for constant values of $n$ and $z$, this limit?

$$\lim_{c\rightarrow 1+}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{\log n}{\log c}\rfloor}(-1)^j\binom{z}{j}c^j$$

Thanks!

Comment: Numerically, I find that the limit goes to zero, independently of n and z.

Comment: NicoDean: Is that true for negative z as well for you?  For me, if I try -1 or -2 for z, it looks like it diverges.  Oh, and obviously if n = 1, the sum equals 1, regardless of z or c.

Comment: only tried positive constants, but robjohn has solved it now, so everything is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive integer values of $z$, when $1\lt c\le n^{1/{\large z}}$ the sum is $(1-c)^{\large z}$. Thus, as $c\to1^+$, the sum tends to $0$.

For negative values of $z$, the alternation disappears and we are left with the sum
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{\log(n)}{\log(c)}\right\rfloor}\binom{j-z-1}{j}c^j
\ge\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{\log(n)}{\log(c)}\right\rfloor}\binom{j-z-1}{j}
$$
With no alternation and the terms on the right being integers bigger than $1$ (generally, much bigger), as $c\to1^+$, the sum will be the sum of $\left\lfloor\frac{\log(n)}{\log(c)}\right\rfloor\to\infty$ terms bigger than $1$. Thus, the sum diverges for negative $z$.